# list items with image when available

Tags: html, css

This Meteor client html has 2 problems.
The first is that a `this.label` with long string overlaps the next list item.
The second is that a `this.image` placeholder is present when no image is available.
Since this code will often run on a smartphone. How can those problems be solved? long string not to overlap but expands its own list item container and remove the image placeholder to give more room in case of no image available.
The image needs to be to the left of the label and centered vertically. Thanks

```
.item-label {
  position: fixed;
  left: 5em;
  padding - top: .6em;
}

#items {
  margin: 1em;
}

#itemsFilter {
  margin - bottom: 1em;
}

li {
  list - style - type: none;
}
```

```html
<template name="items">
  <div id="items">
    <input id="itemsFilter" type="text" placeholder="Start typing, fast find">{{#each values}}
    <li class="items">
      <img class="item-icons" src="/{{this.image}}.gif">
      <span class="item-label">{{this.label}}</span>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: What does the `<img>` element's `src` look like when there is no image? Just `src="/.gif"`? If so, you could target `img[src="/.gif"]` as a CSS selector; giving it a `display:none` or the like.

Comment: @ItoPizarro the `src` contains the url for each of the images but the file does not exist

Comment: This isn't fully in the Meteor spirit but… if you create an AJAX method to test each `src`, assigning one of two templates — one with the `<img>` markup if the request returns a `success` AND a discernible image (you might have to RegEx the response); and one without the `img` markup if not —  you could loop through your data object, calling the method for each item.